# Conditions sent over ssh are performed locally, not remotely

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i \
  /home/backupboy/.ssh/id_rsa user@server.com \
  "[[ $(ls -1 /mnt/dir | wc -l) -gt 4 ]] && rm /mnt/dir/*"
```

If I do this, condition is performed locally. Meaning that `ssh` looks at the number of files in `/mnt/dir` locally and not remotely. Is there any way to get around this? I need to do the condition remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes around it, that will prevent the shell from expanding it, and the string will be processed intact on the other side

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/backupboy/.ssh/id_rsa user@server.com '[[ $(ls -1 /mnt/dir | wc -l) -gt 4 ]] && rm /mnt/dir/*'
```

If you want to use some local variables and have some parts performed remotely you'll need to escape the parts you want to have passed through.  For example, if you want the directory name to be in a variable you might do

```
path=/mnt/dir
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/backupboy/.ssh/id_rsa user@server.com "[[ \$(ls -1 \"$path\" | wc -l) -gt 4 ]] && rm -- \"$path\"/*"
```

Comment: Problem is, I want to use variables inside of it, which means the single quotes wont let me

Comment: That doesn't seem to be in your example.  If that's the case, you can just escape the characters that have special meaning, like `$` and `*` and then they'll get passed along too

Comment: It wasn't in my example because I didn't know that was the problem, but I guess now you mention it, it makes sense. I will try and give it a shot - thank you!

Comment: @Ulukai I just updated my answer to show an example including that sort of thing

Comment: Thank you, quick question though, why add the `sh -c` ? wouldn't it work just as well without it?

Comment: @Ulukai That was actually a mistaken way to correct a mistaken location for my quotes.  I just edited my answer to be more correct.  I was trying to quote the path in case there were spaces or other such characters in the path name, I also added `--` to the command just to protect against the path starting with `-` and throwing the `rm` off